# member binary operator and nonmember binary operator in operator overloading

Tags: c++

While trying to learning operator overloading, I read the following statements from C++ Primer. Frankly speaking, I do not quite understand what does the message that these statements want to deliver. The examples include defining both member binary operator and nonmember binary operator. Is there any difference when using them?

> Ordinarily we define the arithmetic and relational operators as nonmember functions and we define assignment operators as members:

```
Sales_item& Sales_item:: operator (const Sales_item&)
Sales_item operator_(const Sales_item&, const Sales_item&);
```

> Both addition and compound assignment are binary operators, yet these functions define a different number of parameters. The reason for the discrepancy is the this pointer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is a difference in actual use. In particular, when you overload an operator as a non-member function, conversions can be applied to *either* operand (or both operands). When you overload a binary operator with a member function, conversions can only be applied to the *right* operand.

This can lead to some oddities. For example, consider writing a "bignum" package and you wanted to overload `operator+` to handle bignums. If you overload it as a member function, you get an oddity like this:

```
int x = 2;
bignum y = 3;
bignum z;

z = y + x; // works fine.
z = x + y; // doesn't work: x isn't a bignum, and can/won't be converted to one
```

If, instead, you overload `operator+` using a non-member function, both of the operations will work (presuming you have a constructor to create a bignum from an int, which you'd almost certainly want).

A *few* operators (particularly assignment operators, such as `=`, `+=`, `-=`, etc.) are special. A conversion creates a temporary object, and assigning to a temporary object 1) isn't allowed, and 2) wouldn't make sense or accomplish much anyway. Therefore, when you're overloading assignment operators, you always use a member function.