# How to define a friend operator declared on a template in a namespace?

Tags: c++, templates, friend

I have a class like this:

```
namespace N
{
  template<unsigned Mantissa, unsigned Fraction>
  class C
  {
  //...
  public:
    friend C<Mantissa, Fraction> operator +(const C<Mantissa, Fraction> & left, const C<Mantissa, Fraction> & right);
  //...
  };
}
```

And I've been trying to define that `operator +` separately, but I can't get it to work.

I've tried:

```
    template<unsigned Mantissa, unsigned Fraction>
    N::C<Mantissa, Fraction> N::operator+(const N::C<Mantissa, Fraction> & left, const N::C<Mantissa, Fraction> & right)
    {
        //...
    }
```

But I get "C2244    'operator +': unable to match function definition to an existing declaration"

I've tried:

```
    template<unsigned Mantissa, unsigned Fraction>
    N::C<Mantissa, Fraction> operator+(const N::C<Mantissa, Fraction> & left, const N::C<Mantissa, Fraction> & right)
    {
        //...
    }
```

But I get a linker error.

I've tried:

```
namespace N
{
    template<unsigned Mantissa, unsigned Fraction>
    C<Mantissa, Fraction> operator+(const C<Mantissa, Fraction> & left, const C<Mantissa, Fraction> & right)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

But I get the same linker error.

I can't figure out what the issue is or how to resolve it.
The `operator` has to be a `friend` because it's accessing a `private` field (I'd have to make the field `public` otherwise, which I don't want to do if I can avoid it).

Comment: Why are you using `T` in `N::C<T>`???  Your template is `template<unsigned Mantissa, unsigned Fraction>`

Comment: @NathanOliver Small mistake when I was typing up the question. It is actually using `<Mantissa, Fraction>` in the actual code, adjusted the question to match now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`operator+` is declared as a non-template function inside the class definition, but you're trying to define it as a function template later, they don't match. If you want to make it a function template, you can

```
namespace N
{
  // forward declaration of the class template
  template<unsigned Mantissa, unsigned Fraction>
  class C;
  // forward declaration of the function template
  template<unsigned Mantissa, unsigned Fraction>
  C<Mantissa, Fraction> operator +(const C<Mantissa, Fraction> & left, const C<Mantissa, Fraction> & right);

  template<unsigned Mantissa, unsigned Fraction>
  class C
  {
  //...
  public:
    // the instantiation of operator+ with template parameter of current Mantissa and Fraction becomes friend
    friend C<Mantissa, Fraction> operator + <>(const C<Mantissa, Fraction> & left, const C<Mantissa, Fraction> & right);
    //                                      ~~
  //...
  };
}

// definition of the function template
template<unsigned Mantissa, unsigned Fraction>
N::C<Mantissa, Fraction> N::operator+(const N::C<Mantissa, Fraction> & left, const N::C<Mantissa, Fraction> & right)
{
    //...
}
```

If you want to make it a non-template function, then just define it inside the class definition:

```
namespace N
{
  template<unsigned Mantissa, unsigned Fraction>
  class C
  {
  //...
  public:
    // defined as non-template
    friend C<Mantissa, Fraction> operator +(const C<Mantissa, Fraction> & left, const C<Mantissa, Fraction> & right) {
      //...
    }
  //...
  };
}
```

Comment: Does a non-template operator have to be defined inside the class definition? (Up until now I have been just declaring the functions in the class definition and defining them later.)

Comment: @Pharap I'd assume you could do `template <unsigned M, unsigned F> N::C<M, F> N::C<M, F>::operator+ ...` as with any other member function of a template class.

Comment: @cdhowie The problem with making it a member function is that I'd have to [forgoe allowing implicit conversions on the left hand side](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5100574/1377706) of the operator.

Comment: @Pharap I was just answering your comment *"Does a non-template operator have to be defined inside the class definition?"* The answer is no. I assumed you were talking about declaring vs. defining.

Comment: @Pharap You don't have to, but it's impossible in practical, because you have to define all the possible instantiations as non-template function, like `friend C<0, 0> operator +(const C<0, 0> & left, const C<0, 0> & right)`, `friend C<0, 1> operator +(const C<0, 1> & left, const C<0, 1> & right)`, ...

Comment: @songyuanyao I suppose what I really mean is, why is it that the two examples you give work and yet what I was attempting does not.

Comment: @Pharap I explained that at the beginning of my answer. Which part is not clear enough?

Comment: @Pharap Basically it's because the operator needs to be a template, so you need the `<>` after `operator+` to tell the compiler that you want to befriend a particular instantiation (as opposed to all instantiations). But at the point you declare the operator, the compiler isn't aware that there is such a template function, so you have to forward declare it (as in the first code block above). In order to do *that* you have to forward-declare the C class template. So you wind up needing two forward declarations to make it work.

Comment: @Pharap By the way, within `C`'s definition, `C` becomes an alias for the particular instantiation. So `friend C<Mantissa, Fraction> operator + <>(const C<Mantissa, Fraction> & left, const C<Mantissa, Fraction> & right);` can simplify to `friend C operator + <>(const C & left, const C & right);`.

Comment: @cdhowie Thanks for the clear additional explanation.

Comment: AFAIK it is not possible to define a friend function of a template class outside the body that uses the class template parameter, by any means whatsoever. It's just a weird edge case that allows friend functions to be instantiated along with member functions, but I know of no syntax that will let you define it outside the body. Would love to see a counter-example if someone thinks this is possible.

Comment: @songyuanyao I did not know that was possible, neat stuff, though I when I said "use the class template parameter", I meant in it's templated form (i.e. declare `template` somewhere, as you can for an out-of-body member definition for a class template). Also note that this is not necessarily impractical; boolean and enum template parameters are very useful and clearly you can enumerate all cases there.